# Error while starting BI server, OBIEE 11.1

Tags: obiee, oracle-fusion-middleware

I am following [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tjEj.png) tutorial, when I came to the point of restarting the BI server to reflect the newly added repository, then my trial to restart failed !

logs attached as appearing in the log viewer

[image]

edit : I navigated to the nqserver log file and found the following  :

`Oracle BI Server startup failed.[nQSError: 13042] Repository password is wrong.`

Comment: Which logs there aren't any?

Comment: sorry ... an attachment issue

Comment: Go into the log files of the OBIS component. The log viewer doesn't tell you anything about what is actually going wrong there

Comment: original question edited @chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok can't really be more clear than your error message. The RPD password is wrong. Either re-upload with the correct password or change the currently stored password in the credential store

Comment: can you please advise on the place to change the credentials, also note that the sever is currently down, so I am not able to upload anything

Comment: a) even with that problem the adminserver and managedserver must be up so you can still administer the platform

b) in Enterprise Manager -> your domain -> securtiy -> credentials

Comment: I changed the credentials amnd still the same error is  appearing, actually I doubt if the problem is with the credentials provided with the rpd file while uploading it ... I am not sure and I don't know how to change it or even to discard this file from being uploaded during the restart

Comment: I figured out that the server started though the logs and popup message said no !! ... but only after I totally removed the credentials and added it again, thank you